# How to attach a service acount to an existing GCE VM?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

Need to submit dataflow job from an existing GCE VM in google cloud, learned that there has to be one service account with proper scope to be attached to that VM when the VM is created, what if VM already existed? how to attach a service account to an existing vm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the GCE docs you cannot change the attached service account after instance creation:

> After you have created an instance with a service account and specified scopes, you cannot change or expand the list of scopes.

See 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using
for more details.

However if you don't want to recreate your VM you should be able to create a service account and authenticate to that using a private key, as described in the following:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

This is likely less convenient than the using a VM service account because you'll need to manage the private key and authentication yourself.